# Turn list of lists into key:value pairs in python

Tags: python, zapier

I have a system I am working with (Zapier!) which I am using to automate a workflow based on a google sheet which refreshes every hour. The Zap outputs raw row data in the following format:

`list = [["header_1", "header_2", "header_3"], ["uuid_1", "first_timestamp_1", "second_timestamp_1"], ["uuid_2", "first_timestamp_2", "second_timestamp_2"], ["uuid_3", "first_timestamp_3", "second_timestamp_3"]]`

What I am trying to do is transform this data into a json object that is a collection of key value pairs, with the first list element as the key and the remainder of the list elements as values. Ideally, my output would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "header_1":"uuid_1",
    "header_2":"first_timestamp_1",
    "header_3":"second_timestamp_1"
  }
  {
    "header_1":"uuid_2",
    "header_2":"first_timestamp_2",
    "header_3":"second_timestamp_2"
  }
  {
    "header_1":"uuid_3",
    "header_2":"first_timestamp_3",
    "header_3":"second_timestamp_3"
  }
]
```

This is the python I have thus far.

```
list = [["header_1", "header_2", "header_3"], ["uuid_1", "first_timestamp_1", "second_timestamp_1"], ["uuid_2", "first_timestamp_2", "second_timestamp_2"], ["uuid_3", "first_timestamp_3", "second_timestamp_3"]]

row_count = len(list)

if row_count == 1:
    print(null)
else:
    header = list[0]
    output = []
    for element in list:
        output.append(dict())
        for i in element:
            j = 0
            while j < len(header):
                key = header[j]
                value = i
                output = """+key+"":""+value+"""
                j = j+1
```

At this point, it looks like my code is erroring out when I try to append the new key:value pair to the ouput, but I'm not sure if this is even the right approach to take. The error message is:

**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'**

Any advice or help would be appreciated!

Comment: Once the code enters the while loop, `output` is set to a string. This may cause an AttributeError trying to append to `output` on the next for loop iteration, but it would be helpful if you add the error message.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - added the attribute error that is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your while loop, you are overriding the variable `output` - you originally made it a list, and now it is a string. When you go to the second iteration of your for loop, `output` is now a string that does not have the append function.

I am guessing you are trying to create a new dictionary element where you save the string in the variable output. The correct syntax for doing so (assuming there is a pre-existing dictionary `tempdic`) is:

```
tempdic[key] = value
```

Overall, you code should look something like this:

```
l = [["header_1", "header_2", "header_3"], ["uuid_1", "first_timestamp_1", "second_timestamp_1"], ["uuid_2", "first_timestamp_2", "second_timestamp_2"], ["uuid_3", "first_timestamp_3", "second_timestamp_3"]]

row_count = len(list)

if row_count == 1:
    print(null)
else:
    header = l[0]
    output = []
    for element in l[1:]:
        tempdict={}
        for i in element:
            j = 0
            while j < len(header):
                key = header[j]
                value = i
                tempdict[key]=value
                j = j+1
        output.append(tempdict)
```

As a side not, notice I changed your variable name `list` to `l`, `list` is a reserved object name in python and this could be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The line `output = """+key+"":""+value+"""` is the reason for the error, the `output` variable is converted to a string here.
You can do something like this:

```
rows = [
    ["header_1", "header_2", "header_3"],
    ["uuid_1", "first_timestamp_1", "second_timestamp_1"],
    ["uuid_2", "first_timestamp_2", "second_timestamp_2"],
    ["uuid_3", "first_timestamp_3", "second_timestamp_3"]
]

row_count = len(rows)

if row_count == 1:
    print(null)
else:
    header = rows[0]
    output = []
    for row in rows[1:]: # skipping first row as it is used as header
      output.append(dict(zip(header, row)))
```

You get `output` variable as:

```
[{'header_1': 'uuid_1',
  'header_2': 'first_timestamp_1',
  'header_3': 'second_timestamp_1'},
 {'header_1': 'uuid_2',
  'header_2': 'first_timestamp_2',
  'header_3': 'second_timestamp_2'},
 {'header_1': 'uuid_3',
  'header_2': 'first_timestamp_3',
  'header_3': 'second_timestamp_3'}]
```